# I am not able to delete a .csv file using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

I am getting an error Access is denied when I try deleting the csv file from a folder using xp_cmdshell. however I can delete .csv.gpg file successfully from the same location using xp_cmdshell.

My query goes as:

```
--delete the csv file from local folder  
 SELECT @Delete2 = 'del ' + 'C:\Akshay\files\testfile.csv'
 EXEC master..Xp_cmdshell  @Delete2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to user declare and set assuming you know what the file name is. I just tried the statement you have and it erred because of the select.

Here is my solution with the information I have:

```
DECLARE @delete VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @delete = 'del B:\test.txt'

EXEC xp_cmdshell @delete
```

Comment: Is file on your local box? And is the SQL Server connected to the local instance?

Comment: Run this and let me know what value you get.      select name, value_in_use from sys.configurations 
where name = 'xp_cmdshell'